# What's the difference between <T extend any> and <T>?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've seen some times <`T extend any`> in a any `d.ts` files.
I don't know what's the difference between  <`T extend any`> and .

Because `T extend any` never giving restriction to `T` therefore I think there is no difference to '' that allow anything could pass to the generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely no difference. `<T> and <T extends any>` are equivalent.

Let's take an example

```
class MyClass<T> {
    myValue: T

    constructor(myValue: T) {
        this.myValue = myValue
    }
}

class MyAnotherClass<T extends any> {
    myValue: T

    constructor(myValue: T) {
        this.myValue = myValue
    }
}
```

The once you compile this both classes generate the same js code.

```
"use strict";
var MyClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MyClass(myValue) {
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
var MyAnotherClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MyAnotherClass(myValue) {
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }
    return MyAnotherClass;
}());
//# sourceMappingURL=sample.js.map
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I got clear understanding at the `<T extends any>` part with your answer!